# How to install numpy scipy matplotlib and open cv in python 3.6 macbook pro?

Tags: macos, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, python-3.6

I had installed Python 3.6 in my windows laptop from python.org . After that I ran cmd and did `pip install numpy` and `pip install numpy`. It installed successfully. Thereafter I ran idle(python gui) and typed `import numpy` and then `import scipy`, Both worked.

After that I got opencv3 `whl` file and then did `pip install` with it too in cmd and it imported in python.

Can anyone explain step by step in detail how to install `opencv`,`matplotlib`, `scipy`, and `numpy` in `Macbook` so that I can import it in the `python 3` version of `Macbook` or can you just help me in installing in any way but with detailed explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos) and than:

```
conda install  opencv
```

If you want fewer packages installed (Anaconda comes with 200+ of them), use [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) and than:

```
conda install numpy scipy matplotlib opencv
```

Now :

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2
<module 'cv2' from '.../miniconda3/envs/opencv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so'>
```

If this does not work, try making a new environment:

```
conda create -n opencv python=3.6
```

Answer with ENTER.

Later:

```
source activate opencv
```

The prompt should change to `(opencv)`.
Now:

```
(opencv) conda install numpy scipy matplotlib opencv
```

Comment: And how do I compile the source code after I have typed it in sublime text. I saved it as say example.py

Comment: What does `python --version` say?

Comment: 3.6 and when I opeaned anaconda navigator it said to update so I did then I went on to click on environment and there I clicked on anaconda 3 . After that I searched for numpy scripy and matplotlib they all got imported with no error when I ran python . Then I searched for opencv and it showed the version 3 but it was not installed so I clicked on it and then a new window appeared that never seemd to stop or do anything then I just started the shell and typed conda install opencv but it said unmet dependencies

Answer (score 0):

To install OpenCV without anaconda, open terminal and exec this command

```
pip install opencv-python
```

and import module in your Python by following line of code

```
import cv2
```

Comment: Will I be able to open gui and then import cv2 ?

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1: go to anaconda website and download the anaconda with python 3.6 for mac https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos

STEP 2: install with graphical user interface

STEP 3: open terminal and give command "conda --version" to check if anaconda was installed perfectly.

STEP 4: the give the command "conda update conda"  . thos will update all the packages to recent version.

STEP 5: now again go to conda website https://anaconda.org/  and type "opencv' in the search bar.

[search open cv in that box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVx3m.png)

STEP 6: click on conda forge

[this one in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RRdR.png)

STEP 6: now do as it says in the instruction provided there ie. open TERMINAL and run one of the following :

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv  ( i used this one and it worked)
```

or:

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken opencv
```

STEP 7: enter y if asked in terminal.

STEP 8: after install open new terminal and type python and then type "import cv2" . if all was error free till now then the prompt arrow will be shifted to next line.

STEP 9: enjoy coding :)